# Problems setting the php.ini path during Centos7 php installation

Tags: php

First of all, please forgive me for my poor English skills.
    After installing the compilation of Apache, php5.3 on CenOs 7, 
we have a problem with the path to set up `php.ini`

First of all, look at the setting value here.

```
Shell
PHP -r "phpinfo();"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php53/etc/php.ini
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php53/etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)


Web
<? phpinfo(); ?>
Configuration File (php.ini) Path        
/usr/local/php53/lib

Loaded Configuration File                 
(none)

Scan this dir for additional .ini files
/usr/local/php53/etc/php.d

Additional .ini files parsed             
(none)
```

Found the php ini-production file in the source file.
Changed the asp_tag value in the php.ini file to On.
By changing the name to php ini. 
Move to 
    `/usr/local/php53/lib/php.ini` 
path

I started the Apache again, but the settings haven't changed.
I want to know how to change `php.ini`
Please reply.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: The `php_info` shows the ini path as being where you changed it? Why are you installing 5.3 your should use probably 7.3 at this point.

Comment: The operating server consists of 5.3. The php5.3 was being installed for testing.

Comment: You need to check the php.ini file location with `php_info()` in a webpage instead of shell, because this is 2 differents environment that doesn't use the same php.ini